# is it possible VBA excel to call API DataRoboot?

Tags: excel, vba, api, datarobot

in VBA, could we use VBA excel to call API from Prediction DataRobot?

Does anyone know about the template script?
Thanks

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can send API requests using VBA! Here is the very basic function that I use to do simple API requests. It works for me with GET requests on most websites. For POST or PUT, you will need to know their specific URL Scheme and Body text format.

```vb
Private Function XML_API( _
                ByVal URL As String, _
                ByVal Action As String, _
                Optional Body As String = "") As String
                
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    http.Open Action, URL, False
    
    'Default Headers
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
    ''''''''''''''''

    'Send
    If Body <> "" Then
        http.Send CVar(Body)
    Else
        http.Send
    End If
    
    'Interpret Response
    If http.Status = 200 And Action <> "GET" Then
        XML_API = "Successfully Sent!"
    Else
        If http.Status <> 200 And http.responsetext = "" Then
            XML_API = http.statustext
        Else
            XML_API = http.responsetext
        End If
    End If
    
End Function
```