# Troubled with importing a csv. file from download link

Tags: excel, vba, csv, internet-explorer, download

Im trying to automate a csv. download from an IE link.
I have managed to open the web browser but a popup window appears asking to choose "save""open".
What im unable to do is clicking the "save" button with a VB command. tried doing so with `SendKeys` but it isnt working. while searching for a solution i saw it might be related with bringing the popup window to focus, and tried that as well, though unsuccessfully.

Here is what i made so far: (this script is in the Module)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub NavigateToURL(ByVal argURL As String)

On Error Resume Next

    Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Integer = 4

    Dim objIE As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With objIE
      .Visible = True
      .Silent = True
      .navigate argURL
      Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
     Loop
   End With

   ''Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True

   objIE.Quit
   Set objIE = Nothing

 End Sub
```

and this is in an ActiveX commandbutton which runs the script:

```
Private Sub cmdARKK_Click()

  Call NavigateToURL("https://etfdb.com/holdings-export/2062/")
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))   '''for the browser to start
  Application.SendKeys "{TAB}", True    '''just a test to try and see if the popup window reacts to the command    

End Sub
```

Note: the download link from the website is available only for premium users.

Open to any suggestions.  If someone can help with the `SendKeys` it would be perfect for the rest of my project.
Thanks to the helpers!

Comment: If you can't get it working, it might be worth trying an API GET request at that url instead of an IE browser request. You can send API requests using the [WinHttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest) Object. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67267332/14608750)'s a simple function I made to do it.

Comment: Is the popup IE download prompt like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdYhC.png? If so, you can press Ctrl+S to save it. You can simulate pressing Ctrl+S in VBA using `Application.SendKeys "%{s}"`. If the popup is not like above, please provide the screenshot of the popup so that we can have a better understanding of the issue.

Comment: @YuZhou 
the pop is same as you mentioned. i tried to use `Application.SendKeys` in a lot of variations but it didnt work. you can look at the script i attached, on the ActiveX button what i tried. maybe youll know the right way to use it..

Comment: It seems that you execute `objIE.Quit` and `Set objIE = Nothing` first, then you execute `Application.SendKeys`. It won't work if IE is quit. Have you tried to wait and SendKeys before quit IE? Besides, is there any error when you execute the code?