# Taking Postman Output and converting to use with VBA to make Post request

Tags: vba, post, postman

This is the postman code.  How do I convert to use with VBA.  I have been unable to get the body to read as string.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.web.com' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'CME-Application-Version:  CSET' \
--header 'CME-Application-Vendor: CCC' \
--header 'CME-Application-Name: DDD' \
--header 'CME-Request-ID: 20190722' \
--header 'CME-Transact-Time: 23-AUG-2022 09:30' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic AAA' \
--data-raw '{
       "payload": {
              "legs": [
                     {
                           "sideInd": "BUY",
                           "strategyRatio": 1,
                           "symbol": "EW4Q2 P4120"
                     },
                     {
                           "sideInd": "BUY",
                           "strategyRatio": 1,
                           "symbol": "EW4Q2 C4160"
                     },

              ]
       }
}
```

'
Thanks!

Comment: I wrote a function to help make simple API requests in VBA. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67267332/14608750).

Comment: When I copy the Body from Postman to the Body string section I get an error.  Any idea why?

Comment: It looks like your body is json, make sure the headers are set to json and the website is ready to communicate using json.

Comment: The VBA gives me an error.  I haven't gotten to send it out yet.  Again all the code I posted worked in and is from Postman.  I need help converting it so VBA will send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my API function to handle a Collection of headers, so it will be easier to change and set different headers to suit your needs. I have adapted your cURL postman script into VBA:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim Body As String
    Body = "{ ""payload"": { ""legs"": [ { ""sideInd"": ""BUY"", ""strategyRatio"": 1, ""symbol"": ""EW4Q2 P4120"" }, { ""sideInd"": ""BUY"", ""strategyRatio"": 1, ""symbol"": ""EW4Q2 C4160"" }, ] } }"

    Dim Headers As New Collection
    Headers.Add Array("Accept", "application/json")
    Headers.Add Array("Content-Type", "application/json")
    Headers.Add Array("CME-Application-Version", "CSET")
    Headers.Add Array("CME-Application-Vendor", "CCC")
    Headers.Add Array("CME-Application-Name", "DDD")
    Headers.Add Array("CME-Request-ID", "20190722")
    Headers.Add Array("CME-Transact-Time", "23-AUG-2022 09:30")
    Headers.Add Array("Authorization", "Basic AAA")
    
    Dim Response As String
    Response = XML_API("https://api.web.com", "POST", Body, Headers)
    Debug.Print Response
End Sub

Private Function XML_API( _
                ByVal URL As String, _
                ByVal Action As String, _
                Optional Body As String = "", _
                Optional Headers As Collection) As String
                
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    http.Open Action, URL, False
    
    
    'Headers
    Dim Header As Variant
    For Each Header In Headers
        http.setRequestHeader Header(0), Header(1)
    Next
    
    'Send
    If Body <> "" Then
        http.Send CVar(Body)
    Else
        http.Send
    End If
    
    'Interpret Response
    If http.Status = 200 And Action <> "GET" Then
        XML_API = "Successfully Sent!"
    Else
        If http.Status <> 200 And http.responsetext = "" Then
            XML_API = http.statustext
        Else
            XML_API = http.responsetext
        End If
    End If
    
End Function
```

I tested this answer and I was not able to get a response from "https://api.web.com". Make sure the URL you are trying to contact is ready to accept API requests.

Comment: That is amazing.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you.  If I could trouble one more time, I attempted to modify your code to handle two variables in the body.

Comment: What am I doing wrong?                                                                                                             
    Dim legone As String                                                                                                  legone = Sheet3.Range("AA1").Value                                                         
  Body = "{ ""payload"": { ""legs"": [ { ""sideInd"": ""BUY"", ""strategyRatio"": 1, ""symbol"": ""legone.value"" }

Comment: @MichaelBromiley you have to join it into the string as a variable value, `"The speedometer reading is " & myValue & " kmph."` This way VBA knows that you're not meaning to literally include the letters "myValue" inside the string, but as a value to concatenate into the string. `Body = "{ ""payload"": { ""legs"": [ { ""sideInd"": ""BUY"", ""strategyRatio"": 1, ""symbol"": """ & legone.value & """ }"`