# Excel VBA API Post Request BODY

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create API request from my Excel VBA, already have figured out my headers and now I am stuck with request body part. My goal is to have API request body as below:

```
{
  "query":
    [
    {"name": "=John Doe"}
    ]
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
Set json_dict = New Dictionary
json_dict("name") = "John Doe"
TempTxt = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(json_dict)
MsgBox (TempTxt)
```

Result from code above is

```
{"name":"SVR-S0128"}
```

Comment: You will need to learn about the [XMLHTTPRequest Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760305(v=vs.85)). I wrote a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67267332/14608750) which can help make simple API requests with or without body text.

Comment: As for your JSON text issue... I've never had much success with JSON in VBA, so hopefully someone else can help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

Using VBA-JSON:

```vb
Dim json As Object
    
Set json = New Dictionary
json.Add "query", New Collection
json("query").Add New Dictionary
json("query")(1).Add "name", "John Doe"
    
Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(json, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! I also came up with this code:

```
Set json_query = New Dictionary
Set json_name = New Dictionary
json_name("name") = "John Doe"
json_query.Add "query", Array(json_name)
TempTxt = JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(json_query)
```

Comment: add comments to the accepted answer